# Fetching data from server through Redux (Action & Reducer) fails to store the data in the State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

I'm trying to fetch data through Redux (with actions & reducers) and store it in a ReactTable

Here is the Table :

```
// MisleadLeadsTable
import React from "react";
import "react-table-v6/react-table.css";
import ReactTable from "react-table-v6";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {
  getLeadsNotValid,
  updateSpecificNotValidLead
} from "../../actions/leads";
import Spinner from "../layout/Spinner";

class MisleadLeadsTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    const { getLeadsNotValid } = props;
    // Going to get data from the Server
    // Call the Action and use the Reducer
    getLeadsNotValid();

    // Later put the data in the state
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
    this.renderEditable = this.renderEditable.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // TODO 
    const { leadsNotValid } = this.props;
    this.setState({
      data: leadsNotValid
    });
  }

  // Edit the cells
  renderEditable(cellInfo) {
    return (
      <div
        style={{ backgroundColor: "#fafafa" }}
        contentEditable
        suppressContentEditableWarning
        onBlur={e => {
          const data = [...this.state.data];
          data[cellInfo.index][cellInfo.column.id] = e.target.innerHTML;
          this.setState({ data });
        }}
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: this.state.data[cellInfo.index][cellInfo.column.id]
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    // loading data or not
    const { loadingData } = this.props;

    // This "data" should hold the fetched data from the server
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        {loadingData ? (
          <Spinner />
        ) : (
          <div>
            <ReactTable
              data={data}
              columns={[
                {
                  Header: "Business Name",
                  accessor: "BusinessName"
                  // Cell: this.renderEditable
                }
              ]}
              defaultPageSize={10}
              className="-striped -highlight"
            />
            <br />
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  loadingData: state.leadReducer.loadingData,
  leadsNotValid: state.leadReducer.leadsNotValid
});

const mapDispatchToProps = { getLeadsNotValid, updateSpecificNotValidLead };

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MisleadLeadsTable);
```

However when I try to store the data in the State (in `componentDidMount`) it always comes back empty , and when the table is being rendered it gets an empty array.

It is crucial to store the data in the State because I'm trying to implement an editable table.

The data is stored in `leadsNotValid` , and if I do :

```
<ReactTable
  data={leadsNotValid}          // Notice !! Changed this
  columns={[
    {
      Header: "Business Name",
      accessor: "BusinessName"
      // Cell: this.renderEditable
    }
  ]}
  defaultPageSize={10}
  className="-striped -highlight"
/>
```

Then the data is presented successfully to the user , however it's not in the State of the component.

How can I put the `leadsNotValid` in the State using `setState` ?

Here are the Action & Reducer if it's needed (THEY WORK GREAT !) :

Action :

```
import axios from "axios";
import {
  REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID,
  REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID_SUCCESS,
  UPDATED_SUCCESSFULLY_A_NOT_VALID_LEAD_THAT_NOW_IS_VALID,
  UPDATE_A_SINGLE_NOT_VALID_LEAD
} from "./types";

export const updateSpecificNotValidLead = updatedLead => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: UPDATE_A_SINGLE_NOT_VALID_LEAD
  });

  const config = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };
  const body = JSON.stringify({ updatedLead });

  const res = await axios.post(
    ".......API/Something1/....",
    body,
    config
  );

  if (res !== null && res.data !== null) {
    dispatch({
      type: UPDATED_SUCCESSFULLY_A_NOT_VALID_LEAD_THAT_NOW_IS_VALID
    });
  }
};


export const getLeadsNotValid = () => async dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID
  });

  const res = await axios.get(".......API/Something2/....");
  if (res !== null && res.data !== null) {
    dispatch({
      type: REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID_SUCCESS,
      payload: res.data
    });
  }
};
```

Reducer :

```
import {
  GET_MAIN_LEADS_SUCCESS,
  REQUEST_MAIN_LEADS,
  RELOAD_DATA_MAIN_LEADS_TABLE,
  REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID,
  REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID_SUCCESS,
  UPDATE_A_SINGLE_NOT_VALID_LEAD,
  UPDATED_SUCCESSFULLY_A_NOT_VALID_LEAD_THAT_NOW_IS_VALID
} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
  mainLeadsClients: [],
  loadingData: null, // general loader
  reloadMainLeadTable: 0,
  reloadMisleadTable: 0,
  leadsNotValid: []
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  const { type, payload } = action;
  switch (type) {
    case REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID:
      return {
        ...state,
        loadingData: true
      };

    case REQUEST_LEADS_NOT_VALID_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loadingData: false,
        leadsNotValid: payload
      };
    case UPDATE_A_SINGLE_NOT_VALID_LEAD:
      return {
        ...state,
        loadingData: true
      };
    case UPDATED_SUCCESSFULLY_A_NOT_VALID_LEAD_THAT_NOW_IS_VALID:
      return {
        ...state,
        reloadMisleadTable: state.reloadMisleadTable + 1,
        loadingData: false
      };


    // ... more 

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to write super(props) instead of super() in order to access props in the constructor.